# Select info from deleted rows using DELETE ... RETURNING

Tags: sql, mariadb, sql-injection

I am studying SQL injections and I am currently struggling with the following. I have a query similar to this one:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE user_id = $id
```

and I am supposed to inject SQL code to delete a certain row on the `$id` parameter.

Since the server DBMS is MariaDB I have come up with the following:

```
1 
UNION 
SELECT first_name,null 
FROM (delete FROM users 
      WHERE user_id=7 RETURNING first_name)
```

My idea being to do an union between the selected part and the rows that where deleted using the returning option. The final query would look like this:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE user_id = $id 
UNION 
SELECT first_name,null FROM (DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id=7 
                            RETURNING first_name)
```

This is supposed to join the information deleted with the one originally queried, and allow the DELETE to be executed, which is the key idea here. I have not been able to inject the more obvious payload of

```
1; DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id=7
```

for some reason, I think the driver in use does not allow multi queries or something like that. As far as I can tell the RETURNING way should work, but it does not, and I have modified it several times, so I am not sure if there is a restriction about it that I don't know or what, can someone help with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not how `RETURNING` works. `first_name` is available to the calling code to retrieve separately, not added to the result set (which `DELETE` doesn't produce).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález first, thanks for the edits :) Made it much clearer, will try doing it this way next time. Now, onto your comment, lets see if I understand what you mean. You are essentially saying that RETURNING does not produce data for SELECT to act upon right? But what do you mean by: "is available to the calling code to retrieve separately"? I don't get that part, maybe because of me not being familiar enough with this topic, could you explain?

Comment: I think that @ÁlvaroGonzález is saying that in mariadb the delete statement doesn't produce a result set in the same way that a select clause does, and therefore won't work in this context.  I can't independently verify this but it seems reasonable.

Comment: Sorry for the "available to the calling code to retrieve separately" part, it's confusing because I had Oracle in mind, where such clause has a different behaviour (your application code binds output parameters to the SQL statement and values from the `RETURNING` clause are saved into those variables). MariaDB implementation is different. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: [Documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insertreturning/) doesn't say anything about the result-set being "special", but [in practice](https://dbfiddle.uk/AyAgLO_h) it seems to be.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I understand, I did find in the docs https://mariadb.com/kb/en/delete/#returning that it returned "It is possible to return a resultset of the deleted rows for a single table to the client by using the syntax DELETE ... RETURNING select_expr [, select_expr2 ...]]" But also, like you, in practice couldn't make it work for my use cases. So confusion grew :/ But, it seems that it is not possible to do what I wanted in any way, as I have kept trying to no avail. Thanks for the explanation though ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether `DELETE...RETURNING` returns a result set or not, it isn't permitted in a subquery.

Likewise, some other statements that return a result set, like `CALL` or `SHOW`, are not permitted in a subquery.

The only things you can put inside a subquery are:

- [SELECT statement](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/select/)
- [WITH common table expression(s)](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/common-table-expressions/) followed by SELECT statement
- [VALUES table value constructor](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/table-value-constructors/)

To use DELETE in an SQL injection, you would either have to have a connector interface that allowed multi-query, or else you'd have to manipulate the query so that the DELETE is first, then comment out the rest of the query.

Comment: I understand, in my case the connector is out of reach and the possibility to edit the query in such a way is not possible either. So I am guessing that injecting a DELETE is just not possible in the current state. I had the idea thinking that the RETURNING allowed to operate on the result set. But if that is not the case, then there is no choice. Thanks for your help :)